# Logstash ruby filter to parse json and get key field as a value

Tags: ruby, logstash

Hi my logstash ruby filter code is as below.

```
ruby {
    code => "jsondata = event.get('[json]')
           puts jsondata
           jsondata.to_hash
           jsondata.each { |key, value|
               puts key
               puts value
               event.set(['json']['#{key}']['command_ip'], key)
           }
        "
}
```

and my json string is

```
{
"182.1xx.xx.xx": {
    "status": "Failed",
    "result": "Error String"
},
"192.1xx.xx.xx": {
    "status": "Success"
}
}
```

I need final result should be like this. how to insert the key value to inside the json block.

```
{
"182.1xx.xx.xx": {
    "host"   : "182.1xx.xx.xx"
    "status": "Failed",
    "result": "Error String"
},
"192.1xx.xx.xx": {
    "host"   : "192.1xx.xx.xx"
    "status": "Success"
}
}
```

But when i try to insert the host value that i can extracted from the json key its throwing me exception as "Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of String into Integer".

please help me to fix out this thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally errors like this are caused when you receive events that don't have the field you are trying to de-reference present.  If you surround your ruby filter with:

```
if [json] {
// ruby filter here
}
```

the error will likely go away.  Even if your source data always has the value populated, I've run into situations where you get events that you might not be expecting in the filter.